# Return 'No data' if cell is blank, have '0' or 'N/A'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi would you guys be able to help me with following:

I hae a long list of names, but some cells contains zero, N/A or is blank. I'm not interested in filtering them away as the other columns are relevant to me.

Was thinkng to create another column which would return 'no data' .

How can I get excel to return 'No data' if cell is blank, have '0' or 'N/A'

Comment: You'll just need to create a formula using `IF` and  `OR` functions. Also, this question isn't really about programming... it belongs to SuperUser.com better than here

Answer (score 2):

As long as your names are all strings (which I expect they would be), you should be fine to just use the `ISTEXT` function

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1),A1,"no data")
```

Answer (score 1):

First yo need to check for the error and then check for the other two:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(A1)),IF(AND(A1<>"",A1<>0),A1,"no data"),"no data")
```

[image]